# Fragment onCreateView method not called in TabLayout with ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I have follow this link to implement tablayout [Android Material Design working with Tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Now what I did I use fragment instead of Activity for tablayout.

Below is code :-

```
public class HopitalTabLayoutFragment extends Fragment {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

public HopitalTabLayoutFragment() {

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hopital_tab_layout, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)view. findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view. findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter   {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

and add this fragment from Activity :-

```
public class HomeActivityDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigation_view_left, navigation_view_right;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_drawer);


drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
header = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

fragment = new HopitalTabLayoutFragment();
}
}
```

These are my three fragments which are used in tab layout:-

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("DONE");
       return view;
}
}
```

Similarly One and Three.

Now the problem is that at first time all the three fragments are loaded and `onCreateView` method runs but when I open `tablayout` again only fragment One initiate not the second one. What's going wrong in this code? Please help!!

Answer (score 15):

Import FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead FragmentPagerAdapter.

`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;`
to
`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;`

and then extend from FragmentStatePagerAdapter:
`class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter`
to
`class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try this and let you know soon.

Comment: Wowwwwwww...... You make my day brother. I did search a lot for 7 days but have no luck. How did you find that? Please let me know bro. Love You a lot.. ;) hahahah... Once again a lot of thanks to you.. Tussi great ho my bhai.. No one gave answer and you did.. Hats off.. :)

Comment: Oh Man, you're my life saver. Thanks a lot dude, I was breaking my head for over two days. You made my day.

Comment: You save my time tnx

Comment: Thanks A lot! thaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks

Comment: Was deprecated.